# Ruby/Rails method to return the value of a column in string from a collection object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is a collection object @project_member which has a field of user name. Is there a ruby/rails method which can return all user name in a string separated by ","?

We can use .each to assembly the string one by one. However we want to find out if there is ruby way to handle this gracefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@project_members.map(&:username).join(",")
```

Comment: Interesting. Can we do @project_memebers.map(&:user.name).join(",")? It is a user_id.

Comment: `@project_members.map { |user| user.name }.join(',')` is a more brute-force way of doing this.

Comment: map(&:user.name) doesn't work. Try: @project_memebers.map { |memeber| memeber.user.name }.join(',')

Answer (score 3):

I hope this work for you :

```
@project_members.pluck(:username).join(",")
```